# How to work with mutable structures in the IO monad

Tags: haskell, mutable, io-monad

***TL;DR:***
<s>How do I ensure persistence of values generated by `randomRIO` (from `System.Random`) within a given `do` statement?</s>
How do I work with mutable structures in the IO Monad?

My initial question was (so very) wrong - I'm updating the title so future readers who want to understand use mutable structures in the IO monad can find this post.

**Longer version:**

A heads up:
This looks long but a lot of it is just me giving an overview of how `exercism.io` works.  (UPDATE: the last two code-blocks are older versions of my code which are included as reference, in case future readers would like to follow along with the iterations in the code based on the comments/answers.)

***Overview of Exercise:***

I'm working on the `Robot Name` exercise from (the extremely instructive) exercism.io.  The exercise involves creating a `Robot` data type which is capable of storing a name, which is randomly generated (exercise `Readme` is included below).

For those who aren't familiar with it, the `exercism.io` learning model is based on automated testing of student-generated code.  Each exercise consists of a series of tests (written by the test author) and the solution code must be able to pass all of them.  Our code must pass all tests in a given exercise's test file, before we can move to the next exercise - an effective model, imo. (`Robot Name` is exercise #20 or so.)

In this particular exercise, we're asked to create a `Robot` data-type and three accompanying functions: `mkRobot`, `robotName` and `resetName`.

- `mkRobot` generates an instance of a `Robot`
- `robotName` generates and "returns" a unique name for a unnamed `Robot` (i.e., `robotName` does not overwrite a pre-existing name); if a `Robot` already has a name, it simply "returns" the existing name
- `resetName` overwrites a pre-existing name with a new one.

In this particular exercise, there are 7 tests.  The tests checks that:

- 0) `robotName` generates names that conforms to the specified pattern (a
  name is 5 characters long and is made up of two letters followed by
  three digits, e.g., AB123, XQ915, etc.)
- 1) a name assigned by `robotName` is persistent (i.e., let's say we create robot A and assign him (or her) a name using `robotName`; calling `robotName` a second time (on robot A) shouldn't overwrite his name)
- 2) `robotName` generates unique names for different robots (i.e., it tests that we're actually randomizing the process)
- 3) `resetName` generates names that conform to the specified pattern (similar to test #0)
- 4) a name assigned by `resetName` is persistent
- 5) `resetName` assigns a different name (i.e., `resetName` gives a robot a name that's different form it's current name)
- 6) `resetName` affects only one robot at a time (i.e., let's say we have robot A and robot B; resetting robot A's name shouldn't affect robot B's name) AND (ii) names that are generated by `resetName` are persistent

As reference, here's the test itself: https://github.com/dchaudh/exercism-haskell-solutions/blob/master/robot-name/robot-name_test.hs

---

***Where I'm stuck:***

*Version 1 (original post):* <s>At the moment, my code fails on three tests (#1, #4 and #6) all of which have to do with persistence of a robot's name.</s>.

*Version 2: (interim)* <s>Now my code fails on one test (#5) only - test 5 has to do with changing the name of  a robot that we've already created</s> 
(thanks to bheklikr for his helpful comments which helped me clean up version 1)

*Version 3 (final):* The code is now fixed (and passes all tests) thanks to Cirdec's thorough post below.  For future reader's benefit, I'm including the final version of the code along with the two earlier versions (so they can follow along with the various comments/answers).

---

**Version 3 (Final):**
Here's the final version based on Cirdec's answer below (which I'd highly recommend reading).  It turns out that my original question (which asked how to create persistent variables using System.Random) was just totally wrong because my initial implementation was unsound.  My question should instead have asked how to work with mutable structures in the IO monad (which Cirdec explains below).

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

module Robot (robotName, mkRobot, resetName) where

import Data.Map (fromList, findWithDefault)
import System.Random (Random, randomRIO)
import Control.Monad (replicateM)
import Data.IORef (IORef, newIORef, modifyIORef, readIORef)

newtype Robot = Robot { name :: String }

mkRobot :: IO (IORef Robot)
mkRobot = mkRobotName >>= return . Robot >>= newIORef

robotName :: IORef Robot -> IO String
robotName rr = readIORef rr >>= return . name

resetName :: IORef Robot -> IO ()
resetName rr = mkRobotName >>=
               \newName -> modifyIORef rr (\r -> r {name = newName})

mkRobotName :: IO String
mkRobotName = replicateM 2 getRandLetter >>=
              \l -> replicateM 3 getRandNumber >>=
                    \n -> return $ l ++ n

getRandNumber :: IO Char                          
getRandNumber = fmap getNumber $ randomRIO (1, 10)

getRandLetter :: IO Char
getRandLetter = fmap getLetter $ randomRIO (1, 26)

getNumber :: Int -> Char
getNumber i = findWithDefault ' ' i alphabet
  where alphabet = fromList $ zip [1..] ['0'..'9']

getLetter :: Int -> Char
getLetter i = findWithDefault ' ' i alphabet
  where alphabet = fromList $ zip [1..] ['A'..'Z']
```

---

**Version 2 (Interim):** 
Based on bheklikr's comments which clean up the `mkRobotName` function and which help start fixing the mkRobot function.  This version of the code yielded an error on test #5 only - test #5 has to do with changing a robot's name, which motivates the need for mutable structures...

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

module Robot (robotName, mkRobot, resetName) where

import Data.Map (fromList, findWithDefault)
import System.Random (Random, randomRIO)
import Control.Monad (replicateM)

data Robot = Robot (IO String)

resetName :: Robot -> IO String
resetName (Robot _) = mkRobotName >>= \name -> return name

mkRobot :: IO Robot
mkRobot = mkRobotName >>= \name -> return (Robot (return name))

robotName :: Robot -> IO String
robotName (Robot name) = name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------    
--Supporting functions:

mkRobotName :: IO String
mkRobotName = replicateM 2 getRandLetter >>=
              \l -> replicateM 3 getRandNumber >>=
                    \n -> return $ l ++ n

getRandNumber :: IO Char                          
getRandNumber = fmap getNumber $ randomRIO (1, 10)

getRandLetter :: IO Char
getRandLetter = fmap getLetter $ randomRIO (1, 26)

getNumber :: Int -> Char
getNumber i = findWithDefault ' ' i alphabet
  where alphabet = fromList $ zip [1..] ['0'..'9']

getLetter :: Int -> Char
getLetter i = findWithDefault ' ' i alphabet
  where alphabet = fromList $ zip [1..] ['A'..'Z']
```

---

**Version 1 (Original)**: 
In retrospect, this is laughably bad. This version failed on tests #1, #4 and #6 all of which are related to persistence of a robot's name.

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

module Robot (robotName, mkRobot, resetName) where

import Data.Map (fromList, findWithDefault)
import System.Random (Random, randomRIO)          

data Robot = Robot (IO String)

resetName :: Robot -> IO Robot
resetName (Robot _) = return $ (Robot mkRobotName)

mkRobot :: IO Robot 
mkRobot = return (Robot mkRobotName)

robotName :: Robot -> IO String
robotName (Robot name) = name

--the mass of code below is used to randomly generate names; it's probably
--possible to do it in way fewer lines.  but the crux of the main problem lies
--with the three functions above

mkRobotName :: IO String
mkRobotName = getRandLetter >>=
              \l1 -> getRandLetter >>=
                     \l2 -> getRandNumber >>=
                            \n1 -> getRandNumber >>=
                                   \n2 -> getRandNumber >>=
                                          \n3 -> return (l1:l2:n1:n2:n3:[])

getRandNumber :: IO Char
getRandNumber = randomRIO (1,10) >>= \i -> return $ getNumber i

getNumber :: Int -> Char
getNumber i = findWithDefault ' ' i alphabet
  where alphabet = fromList $ zip [1..] ['0'..'9']

getRandLetter :: IO Char
getRandLetter = randomRIO (1,26) >>= \i -> return $ getLetter i

getLetter :: Int -> Char
getLetter i = findWithDefault ' ' i alphabet
  where alphabet = fromList $ zip [1..] ['A'..'Z']
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have `data Robot = Robot String` and `mkRobot = mkRobotName >>= Robot`?  What you're doing now is storing an IO action inside the `Robot` constructor, I imagine what you'd want to do is return a `Robot` with a random `String` in it, not an action that returns a random string.

Comment: Also `mkRobotName = do { l <- replicateM 2 getRandLetter; n <- replicateM 3 getRandNumber; return $ l ++ n`.

Comment: And `getRandNumber = fmap getNumber $ randomRIO (1, 10)` and similarly `getRandLetter = fmap getLetter $ randomRIO (1, 26)`

Comment: I am amazed that you came up with the shorter versions of `mkRobotName`, `getRandNumber` and `getRandLetter` within ~2 minutes of me posting.  Hats off...   Also, regarding the type of `Robot`, I opted to use `Robot (IO String)` as opposed to `Robot String` (which I agree makes more sense) because of the type expected by the test file...

Comment: Is the test file expecting you to have `Robot (IO String)`?  If so, do `mkRobot = mkRobotName >>= Robot . return`.  Then `robotName` can be left alone, and the action inside of `Robot` is simply `return`ing a constant.

Comment: That did the trick for the persistence tests (as you can see in the code above)!  The test also expects an `IO Robot` type which is why the final type is implicitly a bit unwieldy: `IO Robot (IO String)`.  (Am still figuring out how to get the `resetName` function to work but I can play around with that.)

Comment: P.S. Just realizing that we can replace the entire mass of code below the dotted lines with the following line (along with it's binding, of course):  `mkRobotName = mapM randomRIO $ replicate 2 ('A','Z') ++ replicate 3 ('0','9')`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's start with the types, based on what is required by the tests. `mkRobot` returns something in `IO`

```
mkRobot :: IO r
```

`robotName` takes what is returned from `mkRobot` and returns an `IO String`.

```
robotName :: r -> IO String
```

Finally, `resetName` takes what is returned from `mkRobot` and produces an `IO` action. The return of this action is never used, so we'll use the unit type `()` for it which is normal for `IO` actions with no result in Hasekll.

```
resetName :: r -> IO ()
```

Based on the tests, whatever `r` is needs to be able to behave like it is mutated by `resetName`. We have a number of options for things that behave like they are mutable in `IO`:   `IORef`s, `STRef`s, `MVars`s, and software transactional memory. My go-to preference for simple problems is the `IORef`. I'm going to take a slightly different tack than you, and separate the `IORef` from what a `Robot` is.

```
newtype Robot = Robot {name :: String}
```

This leaves `Robot` a very pure data type. Then I'll use `IORef Robot` for what `r` is in the interface to the tests.

`IORef`s provide five extremely useful functions for working with them, which we will use  three of. `newIORef :: a -> IO (IORef a)` makes a new `IORef` holding the provided value. `readIORef :: IORef a -> IO a` reads the value stored in the `IORef`. `modifyIORef :: IORef a -> (a -> a) -> IO ()` applies the function to the value stored in the `IORef`. There are two other extremely useful functions we won't use, `writeIORef` which sets the value without looking at what's there, and `atomicModifyIORef` which solves about half of the shared memory problems in writing multi-threaded programs. We'll import the three that we will use

```
import Data.IORef (IORef, newIORef, modifyIORef, readIORef)
```

When we make a new `Robot` we'll be making a new `IORef Robot` with `newIORef`.

```
mkRobot :: IO (IORef Robot)
mkRobot = mkRobotName >>= return . Robot >>= newIORef
```

When we read the name, we'll read the `Robot` with `readIORef`, then `return` the `Robot`'s `name`

```
robotName :: IORef Robot -> IO String
robotName rr = readIORef rr >>= return . name
```

Finally, `resetName` will mutate the `IORef`. We'll make a new name for the robot with `mkRobotName`, then call `modifyIORef` with a function that sets the robot's name to the new name`.

```
resetName :: IORef Robot -> IO ()
resetName rr = mkRobotName >>=
               \newName -> modifyIORef rr (\r -> r {name = newName})
```

The function `\r -> r {name = newName}` is the same as `const (Robot newName)`, except that it will only change the `name` if we later decide to add some other field to the `Robot` data type.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful!  (And it confirms the fact that I had no idea what I was asking in my first version of the post...)  This is my first time working with mutable structures and I appreciate the thorough, step-by-step explanation.